# Translating from logical to physical addresses

Tags: operating-system, paging

I have a homework problem here which im a bit confused how to start. I have to translate the logical addresses 0,4,9,15,30 into their physical addresses. Ive looked online but havent been able to find similar examples. I have found questions but with much different given information (such as giving me the page index and offset for each logical address). Below is the question, and i did do part 1 which gives me m=32 and n-3. A help in the right direction would be great!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost impossible to figure the above page table structure, it doesn't provide the essential details. Though I'll try to help you.
However, I'll assume that those values are the physical addresses (probably, they are).

**We must consider the following details:**   
Address space: 32 bytes  
Total pages: 4  
Page size: 8 bytes  
Addressing: 1 byte

Page table entries: 
6
8
0
1

Strictly speaking, we would have to index the page table entry, and consequently get the offset into it.  
So we need only 2 bits to index the page table entry (4 entries), whereas 6 bits to the offset in the page (8 bytes - 64 bits).  
Besides, we should assume one-byte addressing.

```
Virtual address:    (8 bits) - Total
0 0                 (2 bits) - Page table entry.
    0 0 0 0 0 0     (6 bits) - Offset into page.
```

The next question is to translate logical into physical:
0, 4, 9, 15, 30 (It's always better to convert such numbers into binary format)

```
One example:
     PTE      OFFSET
0 = (0 0) (0 0 0 0 0 0)

It indexes the first page table entry which physical address is 6,
and the offset is 0.
So 6 + 0 = 6 (Physical address)
```

```
Another example:
     PTE      OFFSET
4 = (0 0) (0 0 0 1 0 0)

It indexes the first page table entry which physical address is 6, 
and the offset is 4.
So 6 + 4 = 10 (Physical address)
```

I hope it will help you.
Regards, Raphael S.Carvalho

Answer (score 2):

(1)The size of logical space is 32 which uses 5 bits and page size is 8 which uses 3 bits.

Problem states "required", I think it means the minimum bits used. Then the higher order requires 5-3 = 2 bits and lower order requires 3 bits.

Since we use one byte addressing, If we use 5-3 = 2 bits to represent the page number then we can find that the address format cannot used in physical address format. So We can use the higher order of 8-3 = 5 bits represent page number and the rest 3 bits represent page offset.

(2). Just for example, for the logical address 4. It's page number is 0 and page offset is 4.
According to the table, page 0 is mapped to frame 6. Therefore, it's physical address should be

> (00110) (100) = 6 * 8 + 4 =54

Answer (score 0):

- logical address: 5 bits (2^5 = 32 bytes) and offset(the lower order part) always is the size of one page, which is 3 bits (2^3 = 8 bytes). Then the first order is therefore 5 - 3 = 2 bits
- Translation should be like

  1. get the page number(higher part) and offset of logical/virtual address. In our case, for example, page number 3(11) and offset 6(110) for logical address of 30(11110 in binary).
  2. lookup the page table for page number 3, so the page frame here is 1. It leads us to the base of physical address is 1 << 3 = 8(shift to the left for 3 bits = bits of offset).
  3. physical address = base + offset = 8 + 6 = 14

Hope it could help.